# How to access the documents that is retrieved from the search aggregation nest bucket

Tags: search, elasticsearch, aggregation, nest, bucket

I have a query like this :

```
var result = clientConnection.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index(indexname)
    .Type(typename)
.Aggregations(a => a
    .DateRange(fieldvalue, d => d
        .Field(fieldname)

        .Ranges(
            r => r.To("2016-03-30T19:40:50+00:00"),
            r => r.From("2016-03-15T19:40:50+00:00")
        )
    )
)
);

           var agg = result.Aggs.DateRange("L2");
```

But this give me 2 nest buckets like this

[nest bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9CFc.jpg)

This gives me only the document count. But I need to see the values inside the document. How do I retrieve the values in the document ? I used Nest.BucketItem but I am not able to retrieve it.

Also I can see that there are 2 buckets. Why not 1? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after the actual documents, then a query to get the documents is probably what you need, as opposed to an aggregation. You can issue multiple queries in one request with [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html). with NEST 2.x onwards, this looks like

```
var indexname = "index-name";
var typename = "type-name";
var fieldname = "field-name";

var result = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms        
    .Index(indexname)
    .Type(typename)
    .Search<dynamic>("search1", s => s
        .Query(q => +q
            .DateRange(r => r
                .Field(fieldname)
                .LessThan("2016-03-30T19:40:50+00:00")
            )
        )
    )
    .Search<dynamic>("search2", s => s
        .Query(q => +q
            .DateRange(r => r
                .Field(fieldname)
                .GreaterThan("2016-03-15T19:40:50+00:00")
            )
        )
    )
);

var search1Documents = result.GetResponse<dynamic>("search1").Documents;   
var search2Documents = result.GetResponse<dynamic>("search2").Documents;
```

This will return you the first 10 documents that match each of the queries. You can use `.From()` and `.Size()` on each search to paginate results.

**EDIT:**

With NEST 1.x, the Multi Search request looks like

```
var indexname = "index-name";
var typename = "type-name";
var fieldname = "field-name";

var result = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
    .FixedPath(indexname, typename)
    .Search<dynamic>("search1", s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Filtered(fq => fq
                .Filter(fqf => fqf
                    .Range(r => r
                        .OnField(fieldname)
                        .Lower("2016-03-30T19:40:50+00:00")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Search<dynamic>("search2", s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Filtered(fq => fq
                .Filter(fqf => fqf
                    .Range(r => r
                        .OnField(fieldname)
                        .Greater("2016-03-15T19:40:50+00:00")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var search1Documents = result.GetResponse<dynamic>("search1").Documents;
var search2Documents = result.GetResponse<dynamic>("search2").Documents;
```

If you can though, I would recommend upgrading to the latest 5.x version of Elasticsearch and NEST as [all Elasticsearch 1.x versions are now end of line for support since 16th January 2017](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol). At the very minimum, I would recommend [upgrading NEST to the latest 1.x version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/1.9.2) which should be compatible with Elasticsearch 1.4.

Comment: Hi Ross , I get an error here while writing the query   in these lines var result = client.MultiSearch(ms => ms        
    .Index(indexname)
    .Type(typename) ........ It shows that Nest.MultisearchDescription doesnt contain a definition for Index .

Comment: What nuget package version of NEST are you using?

Comment: Hi ross, I ma using nest version 1.4

Comment: It's Russ :) What version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: sorry ~!! :D .. Russ.. Es version is also 1.4

Comment: Hi, Russ,. Thanks for the information . I guess I will have to upgrade to 5.x version.

Comment: Russ, could you please have a look over this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571457/extract-a-term-from-a-column-in-elasticsearch-nest